# How to get length of a specific palm line?

Tags: python, opencv, curve

I'm trying to get the length of a palm line which is highlighted in red drawing.

[image: img1]

As you can see, I've got a range of palm. But I don't know how to get a highlighted palm line's coordinate or length. I tried canny to do it, and result is:

[image: canny image]

As you see, that's not clear. What is the best way to achieve my purpose? How to do it?

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
denoised = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(gray, None, 10, 7, 21)
equalized = cv2.equalizeHist(denoised)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(equalized, (9, 9), 0)
canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 10,150,apertureSize = 3)
```

This is my canny making code. I don't know about `cv2.Canny` method very well.

This is the original image:

[image: original img]

The repository of this project is [here](https://github.com/Da-Wit/palm-beesly).

That is not highlighted image:

[image: not highlighted img]

Comment: What you are trying to do is highly challenging. The contrast is poor and the ridges are not continuous.

Comment: To 'Yves Daoust'
Thank you for a comment.
I know that and now i just thought about pattern or machine learning stuff.

Comment: I am even skeptical about a machine learning approach. But are you after this particular line or others as well ? And where is the start, where is the end ?